# Adding an editable field for Non-Editing teacher in Moodle?

Tags: moodle

A non-editing teacher can only teach a Course, and can't touch any course resources/activities. But I want after every lesson he/she teaches they should be able to write a Feedback which Admins can read. Is there a way to give a permission to Non-editing teacher to upload a file or to add text/note in a new field ?

Comment: Can you rephrase this as a *programming* problem? Can you post the code you've tried so far, and why it isn't working?

Comment: More of a feature understanding problem. There are 1000 features in moodle so wanted to know if there is already something for it or will have to code it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a feedback module/activity which can be set up for non-editing teachers.

https://docs.moodle.org/27/en/Feedback_FAQ#How_can_I_allow_teachers_and_non_editing_teachers_to_give_feedback.3F

1. Login as admin and go to the course.
2. Turn editing on and add a feedback module.
3. Save and display.
4. Choose "Permissions" from the feedback administration menu on the left.
5. In the dropdown list "Advanced role override" choose "non-editing teacher"
6. Look for "mod/feedback:complete" and set it to "Allow"
7. Click on "Save changes"

This will allow a non-editing teacher to give feedback. Although you will also need to set up the feedback questions, there are a variety to choose from.